# Mongo spatial query $geoNear vs $near

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I am doing spatial queries in Mongo.  I need to find all venues within 10 miles of San Francisco.  From the command line, I am getting different results when using $geoNear (works) vs $near (doesn't work).  I need to use $near because I am working with Mongoose and it uses $near.

$geoNear works.  I run this command:

```
db.runCommand({geoNear:"venues",near:[-122.418,37.775], maxDistance:10/69});
```

and I get results ordered by distance, within a 10 mile radius.  Great.

But then I run this $near command and I get no results:

```
db.venues.find({loc: {$near: [-122.418,37.775] }, $maxDistance:10/69})
```

From what I can tell, they are the same command.  Am I missing something?  If I remove the $maxDistance, I do get results back and they are correctly ordered by distance.  However, I also get results over 10 miles away.

```
db.venues.find({loc: {$near: [-122.418,37.77] }})
```

Comment: just wondering why the max distance is 10/69. It should rather be 10/3963. Distance / radius of earth in same units.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have $maxDistance : X inside the {$near} JSON document - you have it outside.

Change `db.venues.find({loc: {$near: [-122.418,37.775] }, $maxDistance:10/69})`

to be

`db.venues.find({loc: {$near: [-122.418,37.775], $maxDistance:10/69 } })`